# Check if value exist for multiple records and get one record

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.Department as follows

```
ID  DName
1   IT
2   HR
3   Admin
```

Employee as follows

```
id  fname   departmentid
1   Mary    2
2   Rahul   2
3   Amit    3
4   Vivek   1
5   Preetam 1
6   Mangesh 1
7   Mary    1
```

Observe that there are two records for Mary (id 1 and 7) in employee table. Now I want to get result with name of employee and whether it works in HR department or not. Expected output is as follows.

```
fname   WorksInHR
Mary    Y
Rahul   Y
Amit    N
Vivek   N
Preetam N
Mangesh n
```

How can i achieve this in SQL2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
select e.fname,
       (case when sum(case when d.dname = 'HR' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as WorksInHR
from employee e join
     department d
     on e.departmentid = d.id
group by e.fname;
```

Comment: @Prabi . . . I'm not sure what I was thinking.  I just fixed the answer.

Comment: I am not sure but it is saying syntax error near coalesce. Are you sure its working at your end? or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Prabi . . . There is no `coalesce()` . . . there was an intermediate edit due to mistyping.